# How to retrieve the children in Django

Tags: django

I have a model Category like so :

```
class Category(TimeStampedModel):
    category_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

What I want is to display all the categories that do not have parents at first, and then, in nested lists, their respective children : for example :

```
Flowers
  Lilac
  Rose
Trees
  Maple
```

So what I have tried is that :

```
def get_categories(request):
    categories = Category.objects.filter(category_parent=None)
    return {'categories' : categories}
```

But when I try to display the children of each category, none appears, following my example, I only get Flowers and Trees..

```
<ul class="nav-list">
     {% for category in categories %}
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ category.name }}</a>
         {% if category.categories %}
              <ul class="nav-submenu">
                {% for subcategory in category.categories %}
                <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="#">{{ subcategory.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
         {% endif %}
         </li>
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

How can I get the children too ?

Comment: check out the mptt algorithm it will save you headaches https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify related name "categories" to the category_parent field so you can't access it via category.categories. You can try using this expression

```
{% for subcategory in category.category_set.all %}
    <!-- subcategory staff -->
{% endfor %}
```

in your template.

Comment: You're completely right ! But even with replacing this, I have the same result : that is no children are displayed I have only the categories that don't have parents.

Comment: Then it should work. Have you also changed your if clause in template from 
{% if category.categories %} 
to 
{% if category.category_set.all %}?